# Why is it my Windows XP and Windows 7 PC/laptop can find and connect to my Ubuntu file server while my Ubuntu laptop cannot see it?

Tags: wireless, networking, samba

I have an Ubuntu file server running SAMBA on my home wifi network. It is set to share a directory under the user "john"

I have a Windows XP desktop connected to the network and it sees the file server just fine. Same goes for a Windows7 laptop PC and a Windows7 desktop which connect through the wifi router. I connect, I enter the user and password and I am off to the races with it.

My Ubuntu Thinkpad laptop, on the other hand,  will connect to the wifi network and browse the Internet, but when I attempt to connect to the server, the Ubuntu laptop doesn't find it when I open the directory and click on "Browse Network"  The two icons that do display when clicked churn for a while and then display the error message "Cannot mount volume" or something like that.

I see lots of demonstrations and tutorials out there that instruct on how to get a Windows system to connect to an Ubuntu file share, but I have not seen any on how to get two Ubuntu systems to talk.  Can you point me to some documentation or help me understand what I need to do to get my laptop to communicate with my file server?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the Samba client installed on your Thinkpad? Since you're in a mixed environment, your server is sharing via Samba, instead of the Unix-based sharing protocols. This means that if you don't have the Samba client installed, you won't be able to access those shares.

Additionally, you might have to also set up your file server to allow your Thinkpad in a similar way you probably set it up for the Windows client.